# Good VBA script fails to run on other computer

Tags: excel, vba, userform, regional-settings

I have a very complex excel macro workbook. The VBA code seems to run pretty well on PC's at my location. As soon as I send it to a German colleague it fails to run in unexpected locations of the code. 
The last problem I came across is a `Runtime error 5` when the code try to modify the `Caption` of a `UserForm` (and some text boxes and cmd buttons as well). 
Previously we faced with the same issue with `SlicerCache(x).ClearManualFilter` but somehow I healed itself... 
My first thought was to break up the nest `With` and see which row causes the fail, but it's immediately the first row. I assume it'll do the same for all rows.
I have checked the windows and office settings:

- I'm running Win10, English language settings and Hungarian formatting settings. -> Code running well.
- My local colleagues run the same system with Hungarian language and formatting. -> Code running well.
- The problematic colleague runs Win10 with German language and formatting settings. -> Code fails to run.
- We both have the same Reference libraries in VBA editor, none missing. (I assume it's carried by the excel file itself.)
- I have Microsoft 365 MSO (16.0.13801.21050) 32-bit, he running 16.013801.21004 32-bit. (I suppose the update scheduled by the IT department.) This portion of code months before my latest office update, so I don't think it's a cause. 
   
  The `sub` called by a `CommandButton_Click` event, and calls the user form `zurueckExport`. The form is deisgned so that can called for differnet purposes, so the captions have to be modified according to the needs.

  I have ran out of ideas, don't see what and why cause it. Does anybody could give me some help to deal with this issue? I would be very glad.

```
Public Sub verExport()
   With zurueckExport
        .Caption = "Version Exportieren zum Creo"
        .Label1.Caption = "Welche Version möchten Sie zum Creo exportieren?"
        .CommandButtonExportieren.Visible = True
        .CommandButtonZurueckladen.Visible = False
        .CommandButtonKennlinie.Visible = False
        .KennlinieFormat.Visible = False
        .Show
   End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Did you try to using a different/shorter caption? Like "Test 123" or so?

Comment: I don't think that setting the caption is causing the issue. It's simply the first line of code that accesses `zurueckExport`. I would guess that this triggers some code behind in the form to execute. In the VBE, go to tools->options. On the general tab, select "Break in class modules". Now rerun the code and check if a different location of the error is showsn.

Comment: We had a macro that needed to run in 5 different countries, so we had a subroutine to get all the local info and set that before running the meat of the macro - sorted our issues with charts, x-axis labels etc

Comment: @J0eBl4ck you are right, the captions were too long, that caused the problem.

Comment: @SolarMike that's a good idea, I will try to implement in the future. Tanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The captions were too long, that generated the error message on the other computer. 
Resolution: 
I have added several different labels to the `UserForm` and modify their visibility instead of overwrite the caption. 
Many thanks for @J0eBl4ck for the idea.